# Very slow execution under two conditions like in the query

Tags: postgresql

Plan query:

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=20465.85..20465.86 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=21363.036..21363.037 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Gather  (cost=20465.63..20465.84 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=21363.014..21363.108 rows=3 loops=1)
    Workers Planned: 2
    Workers Launched: 2
    ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=19465.63..19465.64 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=19548.388..19548.388 rows=1 loops=3)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=10766.23..19465.62 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=7204.795..19548.383 rows=1 loops=3)
                ->  Hash Join  (cost=10765.81..15255.58 rows=1142 width=16) (actual time=115.799..19505.353 rows=3937 loops=3)
                      Hash Cond: (exc.packageid = ex.id)
                      Join Filter: (ex1.notificationcontent ~~* (('%'::text || (CASE WHEN (exc.packageuid IS NOT NULL) THEN exc.packageuid ELSE ex.packageuid END)::text) || '%'::text))
                      Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1044143
                      ->  Merge Join  (cost=9575.89..13397.74 rows=254444 width=496) (actual time=104.064..456.209 rows=1048080 loops=3)
                            Merge Cond: (ex1.correspondent_uid = exc.correspondentuid)
                            ->  Sort  (cost=8011.08..8014.32 rows=1295 width=492) (actual time=96.345..97.537 rows=4011 loops=3)
                                  Sort Key: ex1.correspondent_uid
                                  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 5797kB
                                  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ex_in ex1  (cost=0.00..7944.14 rows=1295 width=492) (actual time=0.082..90.635 rows=4011 loops=3)
                                        Filter: ((doctypeid = ANY ('{201,140005}'::integer[])) AND (notificationcontent ~~* '%success%'::text))
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 12263
                            ->  Sort  (cost=1564.81..1596.49 rows=12675 width=36) (actual time=7.714..132.269 rows=1048164 loops=3)
                                  Sort Key: exc.correspondentuid
                                  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1376kB
                                  ->  Seq Scan on ex_out_correspondents exc  (cost=0.00..701.03 rows=12675 width=36) (actual time=0.032..4.151 rows=12694 loops=3)
                                        Filter: (exchangestate = 2)
                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 20268
                      ->  Hash  (cost=884.00..884.00 rows=24473 width=36) (actual time=11.028..11.028 rows=24489 loops=3)
                            Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1874kB
                            ->  Seq Scan on ex_out ex  (cost=0.00..884.00 rows=24473 width=36) (actual time=0.025..6.597 rows=24489 loops=3)
                                  Filter: ((doctypeid < 200) AND (exchangetype = 7))
                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 2780
                ->  Index Scan using ipk__ds_documents__73ba3083 on ds_documents d  (cost=0.42..3.69 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=11811)
                      Index Cond: (uid = ex.docuid)
                      Filter: ((NOT pruz) AND ((reg_date)::date >= '2019-02-01'::date) AND ((reg_date)::date <= '2019-02-28'::date))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 1
```

Planning time: 4.169 ms
Execution time: 21363.604 ms

**If I remove one of the like conditions, then the sample is constructed in 100 milliseconds, versus 30 seconds, if I leave both conditions.**

```
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE)
SELECT count(*)
FROM DS_DOCUMENTS d
INNER JOIN EX_Out ex ON d.UID = ex.DocUID and ExchangeType IN (7) and             DocTypeID < 200 and d.pruz = false
INNER JOIN EX_Out_Correspondents exc ON ex.ID = exc.PackageID and     exc.ExchangeState = 2 
INNER JOIN Ex_in ex1 ON ex1.Correspondent_UID = exc.CorrespondentUID 
    and ex1.DocTypeID in (201, 140005)  
    and ex1.NotificationContent ilike '%' || (case when exc.PackageUID is not null then exc.PackageUID else ex.PackageUID end)|| '%'
    and ex1.NotificationContent ilike '%success%'
WHERE cast(reg_date as date) between '01.02.2019' and '28.02.2019'
```

What am I doing wrong? 
The problem is in this condition, but I do not know why.

```
and ex1.NotificationContent ilike '%' || (case when exc.PackageUID is not null then exc.PackageUID else ex.PackageUID end)|| '%'
and ex1.NotificationContent ilike '%success%'
```

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like for `ex1.NotificationContent` but if you can remove the first `'%'` I believe you can use an index. Having the wildcard on both ends of the regex makes it very expensive. Furthermore, you may consider using the `~*` operator with a POSIX regex in place of the `ILIKE` operator and define a more precise regex. On top of all of that, maybe handle the case expression first and then join `ex1` after that is resolved. (You can build the query piecewise with a CTE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of building the query piece-wise with the idea of trimming the working set prior to adding the expensive `JOIN` condition (which if possible should be optimized). I tried to handle the `CASE` condition prior to the `JOIN` also. Is the `'success'` string located in a common place in `ex1.NotificationContent`? If so, apply that in the first condition.

```
WITH d AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM DS_DOCUMENTS d
    WHERE reg_date::date BETWEEN '01.02.2019' AND '28.02.2019'
), ex_exc AS
(
    SELECT  d.*     -- you may choose to select only the required fields in place of *
            , ex.*
            , exc.*
            , (CASE WHEN exc.PackageUID IS NOT NULL THEN exc.PackageUID ELSE ex.PackageUID END) AS join_package_uid
    FROM d
        JOIN EX_Out ex ON (d.UID = ex.DocUID 
                           AND ExchangeType = 7
                           AND DocTypeID < 200
                           AND d.pruz = FALSE
                          )
        JOIN EX_Out_Correspondents exc ON (ex.ID = exc.PackageID
                                           AND exc.ExchangeState = 2 
                                          )
)
SELECT count(*)
FROM ex_exc
    JOIN Ex_in ex1 ON (ex1.Correspondent_UID = exc.CorrespondentUID
                       AND ex1.DocTypeID IN (201, 140005)
                       AND ex1.NotificationContent ILIKE '%' || ex_exc.join_package_uid || '%'
                       AND ex1.NotificationContent ILIKE '%success%'
                      )
;
```

Comment: It helped me. I think this is due to the fact that the PostgreSQL scheduler did not want to run 2 times over a huge number of entries. Another thing is that if you take into account the period in the condition, then the records will be much less, for some reason the planner did not see it.

Answer (score 1):

From your execution plan it seems like the first of these conditions is your main problem:

```
->  Hash Join  (cost=10765.81..15255.58 rows=1142 width=16) (actual time=115.799..19505.353 rows=3937 loops=3)
      Hash Cond: (exc.packageid = ex.id)
      Join Filter: (ex1.notificationcontent ~~* (('%'::text || (CASE WHEN (exc.packageuid IS NOT NULL) THEN exc.packageuid ELSE ex.packageuid END)::text) || '%'::text))
      Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1044143
```

All your time is spent there, and it must be the 1000000 executions of the expression match that take so long.

Maybe you can come up with a cheaper test. Even if you can find an additional cheaper condition that reduces the number of rows for the expensive test, you would win.

Comment: if I remove one of the conditions like, then "Rows Removed by Join Filter: 397". 
Where does he get 1000000 records from? This is only possible if it ignores the date limit.

Comment: If you join 1048080 rows with 24489 others, you can easily end up with a million removed rows. The date limit is on `ds_documents`, not on `ex_out`, `ex_in` or `ex_out_correspondents`.